# Named Routes & link_to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following routes set up:

```
map.people 'people(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"index"
map.connect 'people(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :post }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"create"
map.new_person 'people/new(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"new"
map.edit_person 'people/:shortname/edit(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller => 'people', :action => 'edit'
map.person 'people/:shortname(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"show"
map.connect 'people/:shortname(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :put }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"update"
map.connect 'people/:shortname(.:format)', :conditions => { :method => :delete }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"destroy"
```

I am trying to use the link_to function on a view page like:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', person_path(person.shortname) %>
```

This gives me this error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
person_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"people", :shortname=>"efleming", :action=>"show"}, expected: {:controller=>"people", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:shortname=>"efleming"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses around the `(:format)` are throwing off your routing.  Do you need that to be in parens? If you remove them, and change the `map.person` line like so then you will be fine:

```
map.person 'people/:shortname.:format', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller=>"people", :action=>"show"
```

In this case the link_to as you have it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your link should look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', person_path(:shortname => person.shortname) %>
```